# Publish Program in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, publish

I'm new to using Visual Studio, and I'm trying to figure out how to 'publish' my program so I can move it other's computers and run it from there.  I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but there are three projects in my solution.   And if I publish it, will I still continue to be able to develop the original files etc?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so you've written your code, debugged it and now you want to distribute it...

When you build a solution using Visual Studio the compiled output of each project is produced in a folder which is either specified manually, or, by default, in a `bin` folder relative to the projects root folder. Within this folder are subfolders which hold the output for a corresponding build (for instance the `Debug` folder contains the `Debug` compilation output).

If you have three projects then, for example, let's assume one is an executable application and the other two are dynamic link libraries on which the application project is dependent, the compiled output from the latter two projects will automatically be copied to the applications compiled output folder, meaning you only need to ship what is in this folder (along with anything else you actually know is required).

For a (rough) folder graph to try and visualise what I'm saying:

```
SolutionFolder\
    ApplicationProjectFolder\
        Bin\                  <- contains overall output
            Debug\            <- the compilation you develop with
            Release\          <- the compilation you distribute (after testing)
    DynamicLinkLibrary0Folder\
        Bin\
            Debug\            <- automatically copied to 'ApplicationProjectFolder\Bin\Debug'
            Release\          <- automatically copied to 'ApplicationProjectFolder\Bin\Release'
    DynamicLinkLibrary1Folder\
        \Bin
            Debug\            <- as above
            Release\          <- as above
```

You can continue to work on your code after distributing, yes, of course, but you can hardly expect the users of the application to have your latest changes without redistributing the whole thing, or updating/patching et cetera.

Of course, this solution is the simplest form - ideally you'd want an installer project as part of the solution, which is the final distributable end-product.

As I said above, it seems you may need to know a heck of a lot more than this to proceed competently and confidently, and I could explain further details on each aspect mentioned here, no doubt, but it has to stop somewhere. Hope this gets you started, though.

Comment: Very well stated... only addition is swapping between "DEBUG" version and "RELEASE" version too.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!  The application would only be used by one other user, so I'm not too concerned about the updates etc.  I was just hoping for a simple "one-file install" sort of process.  Is there an easy way to setup an installer?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer given by @Mr. Disappointment, you could also add a Setup project to the solution, which will take the compiled output and build an installer (a .msi file) for your program. You can then give the .msi file to your users and they can run the setup program to install the application on their computers. You can also put the .msi file on a network share or make it available for download from a website, depending on your requirements.

Another option is to investigate Visual Studio's [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) deployment, which also allows you to distribute your application to users in a simplified way, via a web site or network file share.