# Deploying Program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment

I have a quick beginner question.  I'm programming a very simple program in C# (VS 2010 Express) at work, and hoping to deploy it around the office.  I have basic admin rights (aka I can install simple programs), but I have a feeling that from the programming end, its not as simple as copying and pasting the exe....

Is there something specific I have to do to bundle it up for installation? And if all the office computers are running windows XP, is there a certain .NET version I should code it in?  I definitely won't be able to update the other office computer's .NETs etc (but I have no idea what they run...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend a Q solely regarding a 'setup project', the following doesn't cover dependencies but dupe / related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625693/publish-program-in-visual-studio/4625822#4625822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First step: fetch the framework version you're using.**

To do this: in your project, since you use visual studio, right click on each of your projects successively like this:
[image]

Look at "Target Framework", that's the version you need your users to use.

If the PCs you want to deploy your application to do not have it, and your IT staff refuses to install your version, you can just change the framework used in the same window (but then you may have to make adjustments...)

**Second step: pack it up!**

To do this: On the same picture i uploaded, you can see that it says "Release" on the top. Once your application is ready for deployment, switch from Debug (which is the state you should be in at the moment) then build it.

Last thing to do is to zip the application: go to your project's /bin/release folder.

You do not need to add the APPLICATION_NAMEvshost.exe nor *.pdb files.

That ziped file is the program to run on any machine, make it available to users =)

Welcome to the development world!

Answer (score 2):

You need to know what version of the .NET framework is installed. It is perfectly possible for there to be none at all.

If you can't get your IT team to install a minimum, consistent version of the framework, then a .Net app might not be the right thing to code. Do you have access to a web server and could the application be a web app instead of a windows app? This would limit your deployment issues to just the web app.

Alternatively, package up your application into a deployment package. We have found ClickOnce deployment to be a pretty good way to deploy applications as the users don't need admin rights to run a ClickOnce application from a network share - so long as that Network Share is trusted. You can include pre-requisites such as a .net Framework version in a ClickOnce package, but if you do that the users will need admin rights on their machines. You could also deploy the application as an MSI and ask your IT team to deploy to the users.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've intentionally brought in other dependencies, a C#/.NET program should be able to run with just the executable file.

As for which version of .NET to use, it all depends. Your safest bet is probably .NET 2.0, but it's completely possible for XP machines to have all the way up to .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks eh.  Assuming its something like .NET 3.5, if I add additional classes and what not to the program (like LINQ to SQL, and possibly references in regards to mySQL), would I have to do something special, or would that be included in the .exe?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look to the next two options VS provides you for project deployment

Click Once
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=VS.100).aspx

Which I find specially useful for intranet applications

The other one is the classic setup project, you only need to include the primary output of your project and its creates an installer that puts the necessary dlls, exe, etc into a folder among other configurable settings

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/SetupProjects12022005022406AM/SetupProjects.aspx